# How to assign static IP address to a device which is connected to ethernet port using USB-C adapter

Tags: networking, ethernet, usb-c

I have bought the new Dell XPS laptop 2018. The problem with this laptop is that it has only USB-C ports. It does not even have the ethernet port. I bought a USB-C to ethernet adapter cable. I am trying to connect to ethernet using that adapter.

My network manager has assigned an IP of 147.155.43.86 to my laptop. But when I am trying to connect to LAN through the adapter, I see that the IP address of my laptop is always 2010:320:1018:6::caca:1999. I am trying to change this IP to the IP assigned by network manager. But I cannot do this.

When I typed ifconfig on the terminal, I do not see the usual 'eth0' ( may be because the laptop does not have ethernet port). These are the two things listed when I do 'ifconfig':

1. enx9cebe87aa06d
2. lo

How should I change the IP address of my laptop? I will be really grateful for any suggestion.

Thank you,

Arka

Comment: your ethernet adapter have a name as exotic as `enx9cebe87aa06d` because it's not a static part of your computer; i've got the same with a D-link wifi adapter (and ubuntu had renames `eth.` and `wlan.` into `enp.s.` and `wlp.s.` with all `.` are a number); `lo` is just a sort of virtual network card in order to make some internal network test (in some case for VM)

Comment: your ethernet adapter is using IPv6 where you want an IPv4, i'm not sure if `sudo ifconfig enx9cebe87aa06d 147.155.43.86` will worked

Answer (score 1):

The interface identifier enx9cebe87aa06d is correct for your device. It refers to an **E**ther**N**et device which is e**X**ternal. The numbers are the MAC address of the device.

> My network manager has assigned an IP of 147.155.43.86 to my laptop.

You will also need a netmask address, something like 255.255.x.y, as well as a gateway address, something like 147.155.4x.y, and, finally, DNS nameservers.

You can then set the static IP address by editing connections in Network Manager to set the details like this:

[image]